# Fatal Error in Launcher: Unable to create process using ' "c:\ci\spyder_1563210361503\_h_env\pythonw.exe""D:\anaconda3.7\Scripts\spyder3.exe" '

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

When I want to open spyder3, it returned me above error message and the spyder3 didn't open. Could somebody tell me what should I do, please?

Comment: Operating System name/version: Windows 10

Comment: Python version: 3.7

Comment: conda version 4.7.12